modulation & demodulation of GPS output digital data
I need to add GPS digital output (in form of Lat/Long) in an existing analog audio signal whose bandwidth is 100 Hz-20 KHz. This GPS data should be added in such a way that it should not interfere with audio signal neither total bandwidth of analog signal should exceed 40 KHz. This implies that GPS data should lie within 20 KHz-40 KHz bandwidth.
One way to add GPS digital data in analog signal may be to modulate it (e.g. FSK/PSK) in frequency range of 20 KHz - 40 KHz and then add this modulated signal in existing analog audio signal.
Kindly guide me if there is any COTs solution available which can be used for this purpose? Thanks
Note: A solution is also required on receiving end where audio and GPS data are being separated and modulated GPS data is also converted back into digital Lat/Long data.

we're really not great on "show me an existing solution": We'd be good about helping you with your own!
